# $E \otimes_k A $ is central simple $E$-algebra

Tags: homological-algebra

Theorem $9.120$ from Rotman's homological algebra states that if $A, B$ are central simple $k$-algebra, then so is $A \otimes _k B$.

In the proof of $9.133$ it is stated that if $A$ is an central simple $k$-algebra and $E/k$ is a field extension then by Theorem $9.120$ that $E \otimes_k A $ is central simple $E$-algebra.

So here we view $A$ as a central simple $E$-algebra to use the theorem? Can $A$ even be viewed this way? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No, it's $E\otimes_k A$ that's the CSA over $E$, not $A$.

Comment: I am not sure how Rotman used 9.120 as $A$ is only a $k$-algebra here. If $A$ is not a CSA over $E$, then 9.120 doesn't apply, right?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is....

Comment: Maybe I am being silly here. 9.120 says for the tensor to be CSA over $k$ both A and B have to be CSA over $k$. But in 9.133 A is not CSA over $E$, only E is. so 9.120 still applies?

Comment: Here is what's true. If $A$ and $B$ are finite dimensional simple $k$-algebras with centre $k$ then so is $A\otimes_k B$. Also $E\otimes_k A$ is a finite-dimensional simple $E$-algebra with centre $E$.

Comment: I see. Thank you Angina!